# Изменить ширину NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Есть `activity` , в котором я использую кастомный `FullDrawerLayout` с `Gravity=start` , внутри этого `activity` есть `ViewPager` внутри которого фрагменты, и вот в одном из этих фрагментов я хочу добавить `NavigationDrawer` с `Gravity=end` и использую уже `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` и вот в нем я хочу изменить ширину, делаю это так:

```
    drawerRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    drawerRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    drawerRecycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) drawerLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = 100;
    drawerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

но падает с вот такой ошибкой:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with
>   MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

но эта ошибка ведет в `NavigationDrawer` который в активити, не могу понять при чем тут он. Вот код `NavigationDrawer` который я использую в активити:

```
public class FullDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    private static final int MIN_DRAWER_MARGIN = 0; // dp

    public FullDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FullDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FullDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.");
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);

        // Gravity value for each drawer we've seen. Only one of each permitted.
        int foundDrawers = 0;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
                continue;
            }

            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            if (isContentView(child)) {
                // Content views get measured at exactly the layout's size.
                final int contentWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        widthSize - lp.leftMargin - lp.rightMargin, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                final int contentHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        heightSize - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                child.measure(contentWidthSpec, contentHeightSpec);
            } else if (isDrawerView(child)) {
                final int childGravity =
                        getDrawerViewGravity(child) & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                if ((foundDrawers & childGravity) != 0) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Child drawer has absolute gravity " +
                            gravityToString(childGravity) + " but this already has a " +
                            "drawer view along that edge");
                }
                final int drawerWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec,
                        MIN_DRAWER_MARGIN + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin,
                        lp.width);
                final int drawerHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec,
                        lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin,
                        lp.height);
                child.measure(drawerWidthSpec, drawerHeightSpec);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Child " + child + " at index " + i +
                        " does not have a valid layout_gravity - must be Gravity.LEFT, " +
                        "Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.NO_GRAVITY");
            }
        }
    }

    boolean isContentView(View child) {
        return ((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    boolean isDrawerView(View child) {
        final int gravity = ((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity;
        final int absGravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity,
                child.getLayoutDirection());
        return (absGravity & (Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.RIGHT)) != 0;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    int getDrawerViewGravity(View drawerView) {
        final int gravity = ((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) drawerView.getLayoutParams()).gravity;
        return Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity, drawerView.getLayoutDirection());
    }

    static String gravityToString(int gravity) {
        if ((gravity & Gravity.LEFT) == Gravity.LEFT) {
            return "LEFT";
        }
        if ((gravity & Gravity.RIGHT) == Gravity.RIGHT) {
            return "RIGHT";
        }
        return Integer.toHexString(gravity);
    }

}
```

Здесь падает в строчке

```
сhild.measure(contentWidthSpec, contentHeightSpec);
```

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему, сделал это через верстку, просто установив ширину для `RecyclerView`  и установил ему привязку к правому краю родителя:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <!-- MENU LIST -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```